# Delete data from multiple table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, syntax

I have the below query which will delete data from multiple tables

its not working

please help me :

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("delete tblTesting,tblCodes,tblContract,tblScheduled,tblAbsense,tblClock from tblTesting,tblCodes,tblContract,tblScheduled,tblAbsense,tblClock where tblTesting.TestId = " & lstResults.Column(1) & " And tblTesting.Empid = " & Me.txtEmpIdSearch.Value & " And (tblTesting.Empid= tblCodes.EmpId Or tblTesting.Empid= tblContract.EmpId Or tblTesting.Empid= tblScheduled.EmpId Or tblTesting.Empid= tblAbsense.EmpId Or tblTesting.Empid= tblClock.EmpId ) ")
```

Answer (score 5):

Your SQL statement is wrong. You cannot delete from multiple tables that way. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_delete.asp) how it is done, table by table.

Comment: And remember to do the table deletes in the correct order. The Parent table must be deleted from last when foreign key relationships are in effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your deletes will have to be one table at a time - that is just how SQL works. Some tools will let you put several SQL statements together in a string:

```
"delete table1 where RowId=123; delete table2 where RowID=456; delete table3 where RowID=789;"
```

Just verified that this method does **NOT** work in Access. So you are looking at a separate DoCmd.RunSQL line for each table.

Unless, of course, these are all parent/child tables and you can turn on cascading deletes. Then just delete from the parent table and enjoy the magic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it one table at a time, but apart from the fact that you cannot delete from multiple tables that way, you should not specify columns in the delete clause - delete is always dealing with entire rows.